# Elasticsearch aggs: how to set the 'from' param?

Tags: group-by, elasticsearch, aggregation

Elasticsearch aggregation: How can I set the 'from' parameter, not just the size, for the result of an aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        { "range": { "timestamp": { "from": "now-180d", "to": "now" } } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```